# Maven JavaFX Run error org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I created a maven project and added a JavaFX project to it. I made the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SEF-PROJ</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>/home/mrsaiba/.jdks/corretto-1.8.0_292/jre</executable>
                    <mainClass>src.sampe.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the mvn javafx:run, I got the error

Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) on project SEF-PROJ: Error

I googled it for days, but nothing useful showed up. I am using Java 8 and JavaFX 16(I don't want use a newer version of Java). I set up the JAVA_HOME with the path to the Java 8 jre.

Comment: I recommend to use Netbeans and create a JavaFX project from the IDE so you can easilly use jpackager etc

Comment: This will never work because you simply cannot combine the outdated Java 8 with JavaFX 16. The minimum Java version for JavaFX 16 is Java 11. And do not search for information on the internet before you have read the official documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1):

In Maven 3 if you just had a failed download and have fixed it (e.g. by uploading the jar to a repository) it will cache the failure.

To force a refresh add `-U` to the command line.

Source: **https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException**